# Reverse a command and disable su on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, security, dpkg, su

Whilst following an online guide on how to secure Ubuntu server, I ran this command on one of my test VM's.

```
sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add root admin 4750 /bin/su
```

I know the intention of the command was to limit the use of `su` to specific users.
What I didn't realise is that `su` is already disabled by default on Ubuntu.

Could someone tell me how to reverse it on Ubuntu 12.04?

I have already tried:

```
sudo dpkg-statoverride --remove /bin/su
```

Comment: If it's disabled by default, and it's still disabled, then what's the problem? That command will have changed permissions on `/bin/su` to setuid root, admin group read/execute. That doesn't do much harm. If you want top open it up,  `chmod g+rx /bin/su` will do that. If you want to lock it down, `chmod 0 /bin/su` will do that.

Answer (score 1):

I've got satisfied with the following approach to disable `su` (tested in Lubuntu 14.10).

Open file `/etc/pam.d/su`. Then uncomment line:

```
# auth       required   pam_wheel.so
```

After this nobody (except users which are in `root` group) can use `su`. But it is still possible to start root session using `sudo su`.